# CKEDITOR 3.x : customize <ol> to insert <p> tags inside <li>

Tags: ckeditor, yii

Has anyone dealt with such a thing before? I want to customize the display of posts in my little application and I need the `<p>` tags inside the `<li>` tags added automatically when writing under CKEDITOR. I don't know what config item I should look for.  Please help me if you can.

Comment: Other than the fact that you probably don't want to put <p> tags inside <li>'s, there are extensive customizations available to CKEditor, maybe start at: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Output_Formatting

Comment: Hi Greg, If you give more details about what you are trying to accomplish, you may receive more help. What is the purpose of putting the <p> tags inside the <li> tags. Are you using them to set styles? To key on for some JavaScript manipulation? Perhaps they cause the list to layout in a certain way? Someone might be able to suggest a more feasible approach with additional information. - Joe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do that when saving the datas. It's fairly easy to grep & replace with PHP.

Check out this function : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php